# Like statement in meteorjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an issue with regex which seems very easy but i dont seem to find a way to do it , probably missing something.
i want in meteor-mongodb to search and find all items from a collection by doing a "like" style statement

```
TasksBoards.find({ name: { $regex: ".*Fiscal.*" } }).fetch()
this will bring 1 item
But
TasksBoards.find({ name: { $regex: ".*fiscal.*" } }).fetch()
will bring none
```

the /i doenst work or im not writing it correctly.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
var regex = new RegExp(".*fiscal.*","i");
TasksBoards.find({ 'name': regex }).fetch()
```

for case-insensitive search.
Alternatively, if your regex is not dependent on a variable, you could try:

```
TasksBoards.find({ 'name': /.*fiscal.*/i }).fetch()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep both work from the console but the first one is better for my code. thanks